# variable definition is not correct in my code

Tags: c

this is my code

```
typedef int8_t BYTE;

# define BLOCK_SIZE 512
# define file_name_size 8

bool new_jpeg(BYTE buffer[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc !=2)
    {
        printf("Wrong must be recover image\n");
        return 1;
    }
    FILE* infile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (infile == NULL)
    {
        printf("File not found\n");
        return 1;
    }

    BYTE buffer[BLOCK_SIZE];

    int file_index = 0;

    bool foud_first_jpeg = false;
    FILE* outfile;
    while (fread(buffer,BLOCK_SIZE,1,infile))
    {
        if(new_jpeg(buffer))
        {
            if(!foud_first_jpeg)

                foud_first_jpeg = true;

            else
                fclose(outfile);

            char filename[file_name_size];
            sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", file_index++);
            outfile = fopen(filename, "w");
            if(outfile ==NULL)
                return 1;

            fwrite(buffer, BLOCK_SIZE,1,outfile);
        }
        else if (foud_first_jpeg)
        {
            fwrite(buffer, BLOCK_SIZE,1,outfile);
        }
    }
    fclose(outfile);
    fclose(infile);
}

bool new_jpeg(BYTE buffer[])
{
    return buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0;
}
```

Seems I have an error in last line.
Error is :
error: result of comparison of constant 255 with expression of type 'BYTE' (aka 'signed char') is always false
[-Werror,-Wtautological-constant-out-of-range-compare]

I understand that it is the way I define BYTE, but what is the solution ?

thanks

Comment: What's the reason for having `BYTE` be a signed type? It's kinda unusual.

Comment: Use casting to `uint8_t` at the line of comparisons or use decimal negative numbers instead of the hexadecimal ones (`0xff ==> -128`)

Comment: Try using the negative 8bit equivalents of your constants, e.g. -1 instead of 0xff.

Comment: Just change the typedef to `typedef uint8_t BYTE;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I understand that it is the way I define BYTE, but what is the solution ?

Remove this: `typedef int8_t BYTE;`. *Never* use signed integer types for raw binary, you can get into all kinds of problems with the bitwise operators, as well as overflow.

And then replace `BYTE` with `uint8_t` everywhere, since there was no need to typedef anything in the first place. Don't invent your own standards, but use the one given to use by `stdint.h`! It's by far the most readable form.

The name `BYTE` is particularly problematic, because it collides with a type in Windows API, so it will break in case you need to use the Windows API. The Win API type system is generally infamous, so it can be used to make an example of how to *not* name types...

---

Unrelated to your question, consider dropping the && in your function, since this forces an inefficient byte by byte evaluation upon the compiler. Something like this would run much faster:

```
bool better_new_jpeg (uint8_t buffer[])
{
    const uint32_t HEADER = 0xE0FFD8FFu;
    const uint32_t MASK   = 0xF0FFFFFFu;
    uint32_t tmp;

    memcpy(&tmp, buffer, 4);
    tmp &= MASK;
    return memcmp(&tmp, &HEADER, 4) == 0;
}
```

But please mind endianess here, I was assuming little endian like in your code. Disassembly:

```
better_new_jpeg:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]
        and     eax, -251658241
        cmp     eax, -520103681
        sete    al
        ret
```

Comment: The endian dependency can be avoided without too much effort: `const uint8_t header[4] = { 0xff, 0xd8, 0xff, 0xe0 };` `uint8_t tmp[4];` `memcpy(tmp, buffer, 4);` `tmp[3] &= 0xf0;` `return memcmp(tmp, header, 4) == 0;`. (I can't see which part of the original code assumed endianness.)

Comment: @IanAbbott I wrote it just like that at first but it gave more instructions.